# How can a reversible path be substituted by a reversible zigzag path?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

Say I have a thermodynamic process with parameters P,T,V [Pressure, temperature and volume], path starting from an initial state to a final state, to go back to the initial state we have to stay in equilibrium on the reversible path, that is, we have to perform the process quasi-staticlly, but according to this question, this is the answer:

[image]

How is it possible to have a reversible zigzag path without staying in equilibrium? Am I having a misconception about something or is there a clear explanation [also to make sure, I still haven't taken entropy] , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are trying to say that there can be more than one reversible process path between the same initial and final states of a system.  In the example they are giving, the first path is purely isothermal and reversible.  The second path consists of an adiabatic reversible segment, followed by an isothermal reversible segment, followed by an adiabatic reversible segment.  Both paths can get you reversibly from the same initial state to the same final state.

Comment: So, is this alternative reversible path also quasi-static?

Comment: Yes, the alternative reversible paths also quasi-static.